# jQuery Load Set Number of Data

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I'm running a site that has reviews for products. On the product page, I load recent reviews and 2 "helpful" reviews. Loading the reviews is easy using this code:

```
var reviewURL = 'http://www.mysite123.org/reviews.html';
$('.recentReviews').load(reviewURL);
```

When reviews are loaded, it loads 5 at a time. How can I alter the current line to get the reviews, but then populate only 1 review out of the 5. I feel like it should be easy, but I'm having a giant brain gap on this for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation http://api.jquery.com/load/:

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the url parameter. **If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.**
>
> We could modify the example above to use only part of the document
>   that is fetched:
>
> > $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
>
> When this method executes, it retrieves the content of ajax/test.html,
>   but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with
>   an ID of container. This element, along with its contents, is inserted
>   into the element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved
>   document is discarded.

I can only guess the markup of your review.html, but something like this should work.

```
$('.recentReviews').load(reviewURL + " #review1");
```

or

```
$('.recentReviews').load(reviewURL + " .review:first-child");
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had to be something easy. I was going nuts.